# Is there any way of breaking up an Expression<Func<T, Bool>> and get the right hand side of the equality comparison?

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, expression, equality

This may be a longshot, but I will try it anyway.

Let's say that I have an expression in these manners:

```
public class Foo {
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

Expression<Func<Foo, bool>> expr = p => p.Id == 2;
```

Is there any way of breaking up the expression, by let's say:

- Get the member name (expr.Body as MemberExpression).Member.Name;
- And get the right hand side value of the equality comparison. That is, the 2.

Or is this not possible?

Comment: Luckily, I am not really interested in larger than or smaller than equality comparisons. I am more interested in == or by chance .Equals :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
Expression<Func<Foo, bool>> expr = p => p.Id == 2; // Supports even p.Id.Equals(2)
BinaryExpression be = expr.Body as BinaryExpression;

if (be != null) 
{
    Expression left = be.Left;
    Expression right = be.Right;
} 
else 
{
    MethodCallExpression mc = expr.Body as MethodCallExpression;

    if (mc != null && mc.Method.Name == "Equals" && mc.Arguments.Count == 1) 
    {
        Expression obj = mc.Object; // "left"
        Expression arg = mc.Arguments[0]; // "right"
    }
    else
    {
        // not supported
    }
}
```

Here it is...

Note that this will work only in the most simple case, where there is a simple `BinaryExpression` and `MethodCallExpression` with `Equals`.

But if for example the expression is:

```
Expression<Func<Foo, bool>> expr = p => true;
```

or...

```
Expression<Func<Foo, bool>> expr = p => p.Id == 2 && something;
```

Then it won't work.

Comment: Nice! Does this work with an expression like:

p => p.Id.Equals(2) aswell? :)